# 2 different customized (a tag) classes

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to define 2 different customized (a tag) classes, with different class names?

**For Example:**

If i use these in my html code, i can't define 2 different styles for (a tag) with different names!

```
<a class="type1" href="#">test1</a>
<a class="type2" href="#">test2</a>
```

How to make 2 instances, with different names for these? where should i use type1 and type2?

```
<style>

a:link {color:#FFFFFF;}
a:visited {color:#70B6F2;}
a:hover {color:#70B6F2;}
a:active {color:#70B6F2;}

a:link {text-decoration:none;}
a:visited {text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
a:active {text-decoration:none;}

</style>
```

Tnx

Comment: `a.type1:link` and `a.type2:link`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
a.type1:link {color:#FFFFFF;}
a.type1:visited {color:#70B6F2;}
a.type1:hover {color:#70B6F2;}
a.type1:active {color:#70B6F2;}

a.type2:link {text-decoration:none;}
a.type2:visited {text-decoration:none;}
a.type2:hover {text-decoration:none;}
a.type2:active {text-decoration:none;}
```

[**Demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/LRfaD/1/)